# Text selection replacement in ZSH

Tags: zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Arch on WSL2 and using ZSH as my shell with Windows Terminal as my terminal emulator. Is there any way to make it so that when you select any text, and type something, the selected text gets replaced like all modern text editors and Windows Powershell? Currently, when I select something and type, the text gets deselected and what i typed just goes before or after the selected text depending on which side I selected the text from (I have enabled selection through ctrl+shift+arrowkey just like modern editors).

Comment: Since zsh has not any notion of "text selection", I believe that this can't be achieved without heavy support of the terminal. Perhaps you can ask on [su] if someone knows a terminal emulator with this ability.

Comment: That's not entirely true, but the *mechanism* is not related to any GUI-based terminal. ZLE has a notion of a *mark* (borrowed from Readline and/or emacs?) which you can set, then operate on text between the mark and current cursor position.